# My PHP registration form doesn't send data to the database

Tags: php, android

I made a basic android app with a registration activity and login activity, and i used free web hosting (000webhost) for database.

Everything is working fine, but when I register using the register activity form (email and password) it doesn't save the user credentials to the database. It doesn't even show an error. I've checked the code, and there are no errors so far.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "database user", "password", "database 
name");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO database name (email, 
password) VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>









public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };




            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(email, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

note the difference: you have a database server. On that server is a database (or more than one). Such database can be used for some website/ project. In that database several tables reside.

In such table you store the information.

Your insert query wants to insert into "database name" 
You should insert into some-table

Answer (score 0):

Unless the name of your table is "database name", that would be why it doesn't work. Also, I don't think mySQL allows spaces in table names, but I could be wrong.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO database name (email, 
password) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

Should be replaced with

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO table_name (email, 
password) VALUES (?, ?)");
```